# legend labelFormatter: getting space between name and percentage so they line up

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use HighCharts 2.3.5 to get names and percentages to line up in a legend.

Right now the legend looks like this:

```
symbol aValue aPercentage
symbol somethingElse aPercentage
symbol v aPercentage
```

What I want is this:

```
symbol aValue         aPercentage
symbol somethingElse  aPercentage
symbol v              aPercentage
```

I've resorted to something that sure seems hacky. I set left:0px;right:0px; and then add some nbsps.  The div ends up looking like this:

```
<div style="left:0px;top:0px;display:inline-block;position:absolute;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;44.7%
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.  By accident I found this: [HighCharts Pie Chart Legend value alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223616/highcharts-pie-chart-legend-value-alignment/16232167#16232167)

That fiddle and the floating solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set  widht for legend item:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemWidth

Answer (score 0):

use the legend item formatter alonwithe option `useHTML: true`

using the formatter function you can return html code. you can build the legend item as you wish.