# HighCharts Pie Chart Legend value alignment

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, highcharts

I just want to have my legend have the name value left aligned and the percentage value right aligned, I have worked on this thing for 2 straight days and opened a couple different questions on forums about it and have gotten 0 answers so anyone with any knowledge i'd love your help!  thank you very much
http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/2/

```
$("document").ready(
function(){
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart:{
            type:'pie',
            height: 300,
            width: 400
              },
        credits:{enabled: false},
        colors:[
            '#5485BC', '#AA8C30', '#5C9384', '#981A37', '#FCB319',     '#86A033', '#614931', '#00526F', '#594266', '#cb6828', '#aaaaab', '#a89375'
            ],
        title:{text: null},
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,                        
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%';
                    }
                }                                   
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            width: 200,
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<div style="text-align: left; width:130px;">' + this.name + '</div><div style="width:40px; text-align:right;">' + this.y + '%</div>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            dataLabels: {

                    },
            data: [
                ['Domestic Equity', 38.5],
                ['International Equity', 26.85],
                ['Other', 15.70],
                ['Cash and Equivalents', 10.48],
                ['Fixed Income', 8.48]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should set float:left; for both divs inside legend.

http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/25/

```
labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<div style="text-align: left; width:130px;float:left;">' + this.name + '</div><div style="width:40px; float:left;text-align:right;">' + this.y + '%</div>';
```

Comment: Thank You!!! I wasn't floating them, that's an amateur mistake on my part, this has certainly helped my day i'll tell you!

Comment: One last thing that I was hoping to do was to total the Y values at the end of the legend on the right side only.  If either of you could help me with something like that it would be greatly appreciated, but I understand if you don't know the approach! Thanks again

Comment: This is no longer working, at least with the latest version of Firefox.